# Get the name of menu item with wp_nav_menu

Tags: php, functions, menus, filters

Basically I'm customizing the menu through the options of [wp_nav_menu()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/).

Here is some of my code:

```
function custom_novice_menu($args) {
    $args['container'] = false;
        $args['container_id'] = 'my_primary_menu';
        $args['link_before'] = '<div class="topic-card"><div class="topic-circle"></div><span></span><h3>';
        $args['link_after'] = '</h3></div>';
    return $args;
}
```

Essentially I want to get the name or ID of the current menu item. That way I can use custom fields for each menu item, but I'm not sure how to get the current item doing this.

This is a `filter` in the `functions.php` file.

I basically want `$item->name` or something like that I'm assuming.

Answer (score 1):

The object_id holds the ID of whatever object the menu item refers to, this will be a post, post etc. The get_queried_object_id() will give you the ID of the current page.

```
$menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( 'main-menu' );
$this_item = current( wp_filter_object_list( $menu_items, array( 
'object_id' => get_queried_object_id() ) ) );
echo $this_item->title;
```